# Cannot retrieve values from MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql

```
public boolean getDateMatches(String date){
    try {
        query="select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" "
                + "where "+MATCH_DATE+"='"+date+"';";
        pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            matchNos.add(rs.getInt(MATCH_NO));//array list of Integers
            homeTeams.add(rs.getString(HOME_TEAM));
            awayteams.add(rs.getString(AWAY_TEAM));
            matchTimes.add(rs.getString(MATCH_TIME));
            matchDates.add(rs.getString(MATCH_DATE));
        }
        flag=true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        flag=false;
    }
    finally{
        return flag;
    }
}

//Function to get date after given number of days
public static String getDate(int days){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date=new Date();
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
    return sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString(); 
  }
```

The first one  is the function I use to retrieve values from Database when I pass the date in String Format it is working fine but when I retrieve date from system using getDate() and pass the date to the first function no value is being stored in matchNos,homeTeams,awayTeams,matchTimes and matchDates

note: the second function returns correct values

Please suggest a solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure that the field of the DB is date type?

Comment: Not related , but you should pass *java.sql.Date* ! Secondly , create a query with placeholders `?` and set them using `setXXX()` methods . Chances are it will fail fast and indicate what is wrong !

Comment: It's really unusual to see Java code with string interpolation used in place of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/java). You shouldn't be composing queries that way. `prepareStatement` is a perfect opportunity to introduce a placeholder for your `date` value.

Comment: What is the date format in your db

Comment: date is stored as String in db

Comment: the date variable may be the problem. open a database console and try the sql query there replacing table_name, match_date and date variables. does it return correct result?

Comment: @Baris Akkurt : yes it returns the correct result